# Can I Flash Nexus Factory Image to any Tablet?

Tags: rom-flashing

There are several different versions of Android ROMs on the Internet.

I found that no one is better than Nexus Android which is from Google.

There is a webpage on Google hosting every version of Nexus Android.

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Is it possible to flash Nexus images into other tablets like ASUS Transformer or Samsung Galaxy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. ROMs are always device specific. Reasons are proprietary drivers for specific hardware components.

For more details, you might wish to follow up to the [rom](/questions/tagged/rom) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info), [rom-flashing](/questions/tagged/rom-flashing) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info), and the sites/pages linked from there, e.g. [Is there an official Android “Google” ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/15717/16575)

Answer (score -2):

The best answer for this question is you try flashing Nexus Roms on a old phone that you don't use.We cannot say that it cannot be possible without doing it practically.

IMPORTANT- please note that the old phone should be at least of 5.0 inch screen and the current Android running version should be Lollipop or above.

Please try it and reply me

Comment: This is incredibly bad advice. Of course it won't work. How about you try flashing it on your own phone before asking other people to break their phones for you?