# Does Nexus factory Images work on all android devices other than Nexus devices

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, images

Hi I would like to know if the factory images for the Nexus found on this link [Nexus images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) can also be flashed onto other devices other than the nexus devices only maybe other LG phones or SAMSUNG phones

Comment: The reason why there is factory image for *each* different Nexus device might already give you a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, No.

Nexus images are built for the specific hardware in the device. This is true for all devices, even variants of the same device. For example, You may not be able to install a ROM that is for the LG G3 D855, the international version of the device, on the LG G3 D851, the T-mobile version. Even though the D851 and the D855 are very close to being the exact same device. They are even closer than the D850 (AT&T version) and the D851 are to each other.

Even the slightest hardware differences requires different drivers and configurations. For this reason, it requires the manufacturers (or ROM developer) to build specifically for a device.

See [can I flash nexus factory image to any tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69135/can-i-flash-nexus-factory-image-to-any-tablet?rq=1) as it is related as well.

Comment: Thank you so much Ryan Conrad I will further research into it to get more clearer details but I thank you for your insight. also thaks for the link i'm getting to it ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

No they wont work on devices other than nexus because nexus uses pure android while OEMs uses modified android.

Comment: This is only partially true. They will not work on other device, but not the reason you said. There are non-nexus devices that run Pure Android. The real reason has to do with hardware support. Nexus images have support for the nexus device(s). If you build AOSP (pure) android specifically for your device, and you have all the drivers for the hardware, any device can run AOSP. IF you have the drivers.