# How to get stock Android for Gooophone i6?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom

I bought a knock-off/replica iPhone 6, Goophone i6. It's the original Goophone i6 and it's running on Android 4.2 with an ugly iOS 7 skin over it.

Specs:

- i6 Quad Core
- MTK6582
- 1.4GHz
- 1GB+8GB/16GB/32GB
- Android 4.2
- GPS, WiFi, 3G
- WCDMA
- Single Nano-Sim Card
- 13.0MP Camera Smart Phone

I was wondering if I could delete all of it and just get stock Android?

Comment: For some background, also see: [Is there an official Android “Google” ROM?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15717/16575) / [Can I install any ROM for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) / [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [tutorial blog](http://chinagadgetsreviews.blogspot.sg/2014/09/download-latest-kitkat-442-stock_62.html) to flash KitKat 4.4.2 stock firmware for Goophone i6.

<sub>I'm not affiliated to the creator of the blog or the blog itself.</sub>

> Download the latest KitKat 4.4.2 Stock Firmware for Goophone i6 smartphone from [here](https://copy.com/I3oY9IsrZBQL), [here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/22a9mxzf0gjd/Goophone-i6%20fw.rar) or [here](http://www.solidfiles.com/d/ff537973a2/Goophone-i6_fw.rar).
>
> - Update file name: Goophone-i6 fw
> - Archive size: 296 MB
> - Model: Goophone i6 Smartphone
> - Config_version: V1.1.2
> - Platform: Mediatek MT6582
> - Project: hedy82_wet_v116_jb5
>
> How to install the ROM:
>
> - Unpack FlashTools, and open `Flash_tool.exe`
> - Select `MT6592_Android_scatter.txt` from `/ROM`
> - Wait for the file to be added into the Flash Tool
> - Choose Option -> USB Model, click USB Model –> Choose Option -> DA DownLoad All -> Speed -> High Speed, click High Speed
> - Turn off the phone, then remove the battery.
> - "Press F9 (hit Download button)" OR "if upgrade ROM Firmware -> Upgrade"
> - Connect your phone to the computer via USB data cable.
> - The process will start and a red progress bar will appear after color purple, yellow and green circles display.
> - Finish!

Comment: I cant remove the battery?

Comment: Also, my brother bought a note 3 clone, SM-N900 can he get a good rom/stock android on that one?

Comment: Really sorry that I can't help regarding battery removal, I only found the article and I don't have the device to test it. As for Note 3 clone, does your brother have the real SM-N900 or the "clone" of it? I checked that [SM-N900 is by Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/mobile-phones/galaxy-note/galaxy-note/SM-N9000ZKEXSG), and I think [CyanogenMod 11](http://galaxynote3root.com/sm-n9005-galaxy-note-3-roms/cm11-rom-with-android-4-4-4-for-galaxy-note-3/) is good enough, if not the best.